# How can I count the number of unique pairs in a table that has a recursive relationship?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following table (`people_table`):

```
PersonId  CoupleId  
-------------------
   1        2  
   2        1  
   3        (null)  
   4        5  
   5        4
```

By writing a query similar to this

```
Select count(?) from people_table
```

I expect 2 as count result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest method is:

```
select count(*)
from people_table
where PersonId < CoupleId  ;
```

Why does this work?  Well, two people in a couple have different ids.  One of them must be smaller than the other and this counts one of them.

This also filters out `NULL` values.

Note:  This assumes that your data is well-formed -- that is, both persons in a couple are in the table as separate rows.

Comment: this does not work. what if you have: 1-2, 2-1, 1-3 then you count 2 rows but 1-3 has no pair

Comment: This does not work for 1-2, 2-1, 1-2, 2-1 will count 2 instead of 1.

Comment: @lustinBeceneaga . . . I explicitly say in the answer that the this assumes that the data looks like the data in the question -- with both sides of the relationship represented.

Comment: For me, this answer is quite valid in this case, since the table only allows a person to have only one partner. This is validated using triggers in my case. Thanks @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 4):

```
select count(*) from table
where personID in (select coupleID from table)
and coupleID in (select personid from table)
and coupleID > personID
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `least()` and `greatest()` functions to `personid` and `coupleid` 
and `group by` them and finally count the number of rows:

```
select count(*) counter from (
  select least(personId, coupleId), greatest(personId, coupleId)  
  from people_table
  where personId is not null and coupleId is not null
  group by least(personId, coupleId), greatest(personId, coupleId)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dff82bbf6ef2b26818f78a04f71ca740)

Comment: here's forpas 's demo link [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=784b8145bd8a7fd67716d7c87c02a16c)

Comment: I find this solution very interesting. I would like to better understand how it works.

Comment: It treats pairs like 1,2 and 2,1 as the same, since least of both is 1 and greatest of both is 2. So `group by least(personId, coupleId), greatest(personId, coupleId)` will group by these *same* pairs.

Answer (score 1):

below would be the query using joins -

```
 with table1 as ( 
select 1 as PersonId , 2 as CoupleId from dual
union 
select 2 as PersonId , 1  as CoupleId from dual
union
select 3 as PersonId , null as CoupleId from dual 
union 
select 4 as PersonId , 5 as CoupleId from dual
union
select 5 as PersonId , 4 as CoupleId from dual)
select count(*) from table1 t1 inner join table1 t2 on t1.personId=t2.coupleid and t1.coupleId=t2.personId
where t1.personId>t1.coupleId;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question.. what do you mean by know the data

Comment: If there would be a Person with Id 6 inserted, this wouldn’t make a sense anymore.

Comment: Oh, the with statement is only sample-data!?

Answer (score 1):

You can "normalize" the columns to get the lower value first and then apply distinct to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM 
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT Least(PersonID, CoupleID) AS a, Greatest(PersonID, CoupleID) AS b
   FROM nodupes
   WHERE PersonID IS NOT NULL 
     AND CoupleID IS NOT NULL
 ) dt
```

Answer (score 1):

**Logic**

> - use inner join + join table's PersonId = your table's CoupleId and join table's CoupleId = your table's PersonId
> - because inner join will get double rows so it have to  `count(1) / 2` get the count.

**Schema (Oracle v11g)**

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ("PersonId" int, "CoupleId" int)
INSERT ALL 
    INTO T ("PersonId", "CoupleId")
         VALUES (1, 2)
    INTO T ("PersonId", "CoupleId")
         VALUES (2, 1)
    INTO T ("PersonId", "CoupleId")
         VALUES (3, null)
    INTO T ("PersonId", "CoupleId")
         VALUES (4, 5)
    INTO T ("PersonId", "CoupleId")
         VALUES (5, 4)
SELECT * FROM dual
```

**Not Allow PersonId and CoupleId Duplicate  Version**

```
select count(1) / 2 cnt  from T T1
inner join T  T2 on T1."PersonId" = T2."CoupleId" and T1."CoupleId" = T2."PersonId"

cnt
---
2
```

**Allow PersonId and CoupleId Duplicate  Version**

```
with cte as (
    select distinct * from T
)
select count(1) / 2 cnt  from CTE T1
inner join CTE T2 on T1."PersonId" = T2."CoupleId" and T1."CoupleId" = T2."PersonId"

cnt
---
2
```

---

**[View on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0dc69328d092471116da997cd1ea3405)**

Answer (score 0):

First, count pairs with the same values ​​in the PersonId and CoupleId columns, then drop all rows that are less than 2, and then count the rows in the result set.

```
with
  table1 as ( 
    select 1 as PersonId, 2 as CoupleId from dual union all
    select 2, 1 from dual union all select 3, null from dual union all
    select 4, 5 from dual union all select 5, 4 from dual union all
    select 4, 5 from dual union all select 2, 1 from dual
  )
select count(*) as qnt
from (
  select count(*) as qnt
  from table1
  group by case when PersonId < CoupleId then PersonId else CoupleId end,
           case when PersonId < CoupleId then CoupleId else PersonId end
  having count(*) > 1
);
```

**Output:**

```
       QNT
----------
         2
```

Test it online with [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a832bd22ce38cf88b030308310b7f464).